# How many divergent transitions are too many?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian, naive-bayes

I am running a Bayesian linear mixed effects analysis. Four chains for 3000 iterations. I end up with four divergent transitions. Is this too many or can I proceed? How do I know if it's too many? I've read about diagnostics using plots, but to be honest it didn't help much.

Comment: 1 is too many.  A divergence indicates that there are regions of the posterior which the sampler can not effectively explore.  This leads to bias in the samples.  How much bias?  Hard to say, which is why 1 is too many.  Try increasing `adapt_delta` to something closer to 1 or examine where the divergences are happening.  You may be able to make a clever reparameterization to avoid them.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thanks! I've tried adapt_delta up to even .9999 and it doesn't help. Would you be able to point me to some readable literature on how to reparameterize my model? Everything I've found has been quite impenetrable.

Comment: model reparamterization is not easy. You might be better off asking a new question. Point me to it and I can try my best to help you out

Comment: @DemetriPananos Funnily enough I just did! Thanks!

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547317/how-do-i-implement-non-centered-parameterization-in-rstanarm