# How do I implement non-centered parameterization in rstanarm?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, random-variable, hierarchical-bayesian

I have seen this suggested as a solution to divergent transitions. However, I don't understand how to do it. Would someone be able to explain how to do this for this example model?

```
library(rstanarm)

mdl <- stan_lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + (1+ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length|Species), data = iris)
```

Comment: rstanarm uses recommended non-centred parameterizations for its models (I think) so I don't think reparameteriztion would help here.  What do your priors look like in your application?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I've just been using the defaults. Do you think shrinking them a bit might help?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure that your priors accurately reflect your prior knowledge.  Simply making the priors more narrow is not a justifiable approach, though it will curb the divergences